# exibir 1 item da lista dentro da lista python

Tags: python, lista, lista-encadeada

Estou resolvendo um desafio, o objetivo final é descobrir o total gasto com cada tipo de despesa geral/pessoal. Ainda não terminei, mas como faço para exibir apenas o primeiro item dessa lista?

```
despesas = [["Luz", "Geral"],
        ["Agua", "Geral"],
        ["Eletricidade", "Geral"],
        ["Internet", "Geral"],
        ["Alimentacao", "Pessoal"],
        ["Jantar", "Pessoal"],
        ["Viagem", "Pessoal"],
        ["Taxi", "Pessoal"],
        ["Uber", "Pessoal"],
        ["Hotel", "Pessoal"],
        ["Internet do Celular", "Pessoal"],
        ["Outros", "Pessoal"]]

opcao = -1

while opcao!=4:
    print("1 - Ranking Geral \n 2 - Geral \n 3 - Pessoal \n 4 - Sair")
    opcao = int(input("Escolha sua opcao: "))
    if(opcao==1):
        print(despesas)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    despesas = [["Luz", "Geral"],
        ["Agua", "Geral"],
        ["Eletricidade", "Geral"],
        ["Internet", "Geral"],
        ["Alimentacao", "Pessoal"],
        ["Jantar", "Pessoal"],
        ["Viagem", "Pessoal"],
        ["Taxi", "Pessoal"],
        ["Uber", "Pessoal"],
        ["Hotel", "Pessoal"],
        ["Internet do Celular", "Pessoal"],
        ["Outros", "Pessoal"]]



opcao = -1
while opcao!=4:
    print("1 - Ranking Geral \n 2 - Geral \n 3 - Pessoal \n 4 - Sair")
    opcao = int(input("Escolha sua opcao: "))

    if(opcao==1):

                print(despesas)
    elif(opcao==2):
        for x in despesas:
            if x[1] == 'Geral':
                print(x)

    elif(opcao==3):
        for x in despesas:
            if x[1] == 'Pessoal':
                print(x)
    print('------------------------------------------')
```

Comment: tudo que estiver no indice[1] e for igual a 'Pessoal' ou igual a 'Geral' vai ser printado na tela os itens

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).